# Select a label for input checked element at a unknown level

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have :

```
<div class=mystyle>
    <input type=checkbox>
    <div>
      <div>  <!---<< the label can be inside here--->
        <div>  <!---<< or here--->
         .....  <<!---< or ????--->
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div> 
    </div>       
</div>
```

I have a `label` element for that `input`

I want to use the checked state.

Is there any way to create a css selector connected to checked  state to select it (the `label`) no matter where it is?.

( now I have : 
mystyle input:first-of-type:checked ~ div>div>div>label:hover:after
 but ------
)

Comment: Next time, please make sure what you're about to post is exactly the question you intend to ask. Don't keep posting one question, getting answers, realizing that's not what you want and then either editing it or posting a new version. This is your third question in the past hour now.

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with

```
input:checked + div label {
    /* label style here */
}
```

This selector means: “pick all `label` elements inside a `div` element which is immediate sibling of a checked `input`”

Comment: @Fabrizio: So "pick all label elements inside" looks at any level, isn't it ?